# Emmet in VS 2013. Expand by tab hotkey

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, emmet

How can I add hotkey to expand abbreviation at Emet in VS 2013?
At the Option->Keyboard I find all emmet action, but its unclear:

- Emmet.cmdldEmmet0103
- Emmet.cmdldEmmet0104
- etc...

Where can I find "Expand abbreviation?"

Answer (score 4):

`Emmet.cmdldEmmet0000` is the command for Expand abbreviation.
Just assign some shortcut for this command (i.e Alt+X)

Answer (score 3):

After installing VS Web Essentials, http://vswebessentials.com/, you just press Tab to "Expand abbreviation".